# Using pure JS set Select2 value and trigger events

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2, greasemonkey

I'm using grease monkey user script to restyle UI and automate initial input on some weird site, which uses jQuery and Select2.

I dealing with row containing two selects:

- organization (options are loaded, empty option is selected, select control is enabled)
- hall (no options, disabled).

I need to make selection in the first one to force second one to load corresponding option and become enabled.

Lets name orgSelect is a HTMLSelectElement with attached events and orgSpan is a "select + span > span.selection > span" element with attached events, created by Select2.

I can set orgSelect.value (obviously).

I can dispatch "change" event for orgSelect and see selected value rendered. But nothing going on with second select.

I can click orgSpan expecting dropdown action (I even seen such a example online and it works), but this doesn't work for me. No drop down on orgSpan.click().

So, I can set value for select2, but how to trigger it properly?

Comment: The problem is more nuanced - a simple change() doesn’t fire the right events. Fortunately the answer below explains it

Answer (score 3):

Wellp... somehow I found proper event chain. But I didn't tested it in pure JS. Because, first I decided to try to use jQuery from "unsafe" window and since it working I did the next:

- rewrote code to jQuery;
- had wrote wrapper for adding event handlers with exporting them to "unsafe" window;
- found out that the behavior doesn't changed after switching from dispatchEvent() to jQuery.trigger() (I can set and render value, but no further actions starting after this - looks that devs don't use "change" event for that actions)
- figured out that devs uses YII and googled the problem in this context
- figured out that secondary select component even didn't initialized as Select2() after the main select value changed
- after dozens of tries and looking different events across the html body I found the event for starting the actions (it was attached to one of the parents of select2 component):

```
    orgSelect.val(orgId);
    orgSelect.trigger('change'); // rendering new value
    orgSelect.trigger('select2:select'); // starting actions for secondary <select>
```

Comment: Oh man, I’m so glad to have found this. I too had tried firing change and select2:select, but the combination of both does the trick. Thank you. 


And FYI - although the question was “vanilla JS” and the answer is jquery, the same should work in vanilla - the problem is not about vanilla vs jquery, the problem is that Angular’s Select2 does not play well with outside interference like greasemonkey or, as was the case for me, trying to get Selenium to fire JS to change a Select2 dropdown